# Javascript nodejs JSON.parse array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm taking a course on udemy and i'm really confused on how `notes = JSON.parse(notesString)` is an array when it's suppose to be an object (right?) since JSON.parse makes it an object.

```
var addNote = (title, body) => {
  var notes = []; // Create empty array
  var note = { // Fetch user input
    title,
    body
  };
  try {
    var notesString = fs.readFileSync("notes-data.json"); //  Get current notes
    notes = JSON.parse(notesString); // convert current notes into object
    console.log("try:", notes.constructor)
  }catch(e){

  }
  console.log(notes)
  notes.push(note);
  fs.writeFileSync("notes-data.json", JSON.stringify(notes));
};
```

Comment: From this code it looks like it's an array. You commented it's an array yourself: `var notes = []; // Create empty array`

Comment: "since JSON.parse makes it an object" --- it does not. `JSON.parse` returns the value of the same type it was initially.

Comment: although technically an array is an object in javascript.

Comment: JSON.parse do just parsing json string into JSON. it can be an array of objects or simple object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.parse() is required over there because the output of a fs operation is a string which we need to convert into an object in order to access it properly. The data inside it is a JSON Array as a result we are able read it. Add try catch around the JSON.parse because if the data is not of JSON type then it will cause an error.

Comment: This is the proper answer.  The key note to remember is that fs operation you're doing returns a //string//, not an object (or array for that matter).

Comment: Thank you, it's making sense now.

Answer (score 0):

If JSON in file *notes-data.json* contains JSON-array, i.e. some content like

```
[{"one":1}, {"two":2}]
```

You will get array from *JSON.parse* method.

Answer (score 0):

If JSON in file notes-data.json contains JSON-array, i.e. some content like

```
var data = "[{"one":1}, {"two":2}]";
var result = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please add somes explanations editing your answer, avoid code only answer